# RxJava: Call network multiple times with increasing delay, ignoring errors

Tags: java, android, network-programming, rx-java, reactivex

I want to create a sort of exponential backoff for a network call.
But instead of a usual backoff interval, my network call should be repeated a few times (with increasing delay) and then be complete - regardless what the outcome of the network call is.

For example, the default case should look like this:

```
    → wait 1s → network call → onNext(result)
    → wait 3s → network call → onNext(result)
    → wait 10s → network call → onNext(result)
    → onCompleted
```

When some of the network calls have errors, these errors should be logged, but not abort the task itself. Let's say the second network call has an error, then it should look like this:

```
    → wait 1s → network call → onNext(result)
    → wait 3s → network call error → log error
    → wait 10s → network call → onNext(result)
    → onCompleted
```

And when all calls have errors:

```
    → wait 1s → network call error → log error
    → wait 3s → network call error → log error
    → wait 10s → network call error → log error
    → onCompleted
```

I already have an Observable that can call the network where the code looks like this:

```
public Observable<Stuff> loadStuff() {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://example.com/stuff").build();
    return myCall(request, Stuff.class);
}

public <T> Observable<T> myCall(Request request, Class<T> resultClass) {
    // calls OkHttp3 and parses the result
    return okhttp(request)
            .flatMap(parseResponse(resultClass));
}
```

How can I repeatedly use the Observable from `loadStuff()` to achieve my desired backoff interval?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use **RetryWhen** and also **onErrorResumeNext** to avoid the break of the pipeline, in the RetryWhen you can return an Observable with an exponential delay to achieve what you want.

```
      @Test
public void observableOnErrorResumeNext() {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.just(null)
                                          .map(Object::toString)
                                          .doOnError(failure -> System.out.println("Error:" + failure.getCause()))
                                          .retryWhen(errors -> errors.doOnNext(o -> count++)
                                                                     .flatMap(t -> count > 3 ? Observable.error(t) : Observable.just(null)),
                                                     Schedulers.newThread())
                                          .onErrorResumeNext(t -> {
                                              System.out.println("Error after all retries:" + t.getCause());
                                              return Observable.just("I save the world for extinction!");
                                          })
                                          .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription).awaitTerminalEvent(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

If you need to see more examples take a look here: https://github.com/politrons/reactive